# python - lxml how to get children of element by tag name?

Tags: python, lxml

I have a xml file that looks like this:

```html
<page>
    <title>title1</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle</subtitle>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world!@</text>
</page>
<page>
    <title>title2</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world</text>
</page>
```

How can I get the text of each page? Right now I have a list of each page. The following code will print the text of the second page element but not the first. Is there a way to take the child element by tag name like `element['text']`

```
for i in pages:
    print i[3]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can write code something like this :

```
from lxml import html

xml = """<page>
    <title>title1</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle</subtitle>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world!@</text>
</page>
<page>
    <title>title2</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world</text>
</page>"""

root = html.fromstring(xml)
print(root.xpath('//page/text/text()'))
```

The result will be :

```
['hello world!@', 'hello world']
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the issue I am using a "Node" helper class that will return a dict:

```
class Node():
    @staticmethod
    def childTexts(node):
        texts={}
        for child in list(node):
            texts[child.tag]=child.text
        return texts
```

**example usage:**

```
xml = """<pages>
<page>
    <title>title1</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle</subtitle>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world!@</text>
</page>
<page>
    <title>title2</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world</text>
</page>
</pages>

"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
for node in root.xpath('//page'):
    texts=Node.childTexts(node)
    print (texts)
```

**result:**

```
{'title': 'title1', 'subtitle': 'subtitle', 'ns': '0', 'id': '1', 'text': 'hello world!@'}
{'title': 'title2', 'ns': '0', 'id': '1', 'text': 'hello world'}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to introduce the `Node` type if it contains no state.  Just write `def node_child_texts(node)`

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pylxml/web/Element-findtext.html) helped me for a similar task:

Each iteration finds a tag named 'id' or 'text'. If no tag is found, return the string, 'None'. The result of one iteration will then be appended to a list, allowing us to print that list in a format similar to a data frame.

```
import lxml
import lxml.etree as ET

# Initialise a list to append results to
list_of_results = []

# Loop through the pages to search for text
for page in root:
    id = page.findtext('id', default = 'None')
    text = page.findtext('text', default = 'None')
    list_of_results.append([id, text])

# Print list
list_of_results
```

Result:

```
[['1', 'hello world!@'], ['1', 'hello world']]
```

If all you want is to print the text, you could simply remove the id line.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old but here is the code that solved my version of this issue.
Iterating over pages and doing stuff with several of the sub elements for each page.
using relative xpath seems obvious in hindsight, but I think JQuery etc. had made me expect something more "object like" would be available.

```
from lxml import html

def getxt(elm, xp, df=None):
    """helper function to get element text"""
    lst = elm.xpath(xp + '/text()')
    if not lst:
        return df
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        print('unexpected getxt result')
        sys.exit()

xml = """<page>
    <title>title1</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle</subtitle>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world!@</text>
</page>
<page>
    <title>title2</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>hello world</text>
</page>"""

root = html.fromstring(xml)

for page in root.xpath('//page'):
    # 3 ways of doing it
    print(page.xpath('./text/text()')[0])
    print(page.xpath('./text')[0].text)
    print(getxt(page, 'text'))
```

Answer (score 0):

*IF* your children tags are guaranteed to be unique and to only appear **ONCE**, then you can create a dictionary for each `<page>` element, and then access any child by its tag name, similar to how you do with JSON:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lxml import etree

xml = """
<root>
    <page>
        <title>title1</title>
        <subtitle>subtitle</subtitle>
        <ns>0</ns>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>hello world</text>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>title2</title>
        <ns>0</ns>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>hello world</text>
    </page>
</root>
"""

soup = etree.fromstring(xml)

for page in soup.findall('page'):
    tags = {t.tag: t for t in page}
    print(tags['title'].text, tags['ns'].text, tags['id'].text, tags['text'].text, sep=',')


# OUTPUT:
# title1,0,1,hello world
# title2,0,1,hello world
```